# Unable to post API Rest PHP SQLITE

Tags: php, sqlite, rest, api

I'm looking for since few days to create a API Restful in PHP to add record on my sqlite database. But when I use POSTMAN to try it, my php code doesn't work, but it's work (with little modifies) with mysql databases.

Could you help me please ? (This code is just a test)

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

try{
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $retour["success"] = true;
    $retour["message"] = "Connexion OK";
} catch(Exception $e){
    $retour["success"] = false;
    $retour["message"] = "Connexion impossible";
}

if ( !empty($_POST["ville_depart"]) && !empty($_POST["ville_destination"]) && !empty($_POST["date"]) && !empty($_POST["nb_heure"]) && !empty($_POST["prix"]) ) { 

$requete = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO api (id, ville_depart, ville_destination, date_depart, nb_heure_vol, prix) VALUES (?, :ville1, :ville2, :date_vol, :nb, :prix)');
$requete->bindParam(':ville1', $_POST["ville_depart"]);
$requete->bindParam(':ville2', $_POST["ville_destination"]);
$requete->bindParam(':date_vol', $_POST["date_depart"]);
$requete->bindParam(':nb', $_POST["nb_heure_vol"]);
$requete->bindParam(':prix', $_POST["prix"]);
$requete->execute();

$retour["success"] = true;
$retour["message"] = "add flight";
$retour["results"] = array();

} else {
    $retour["success"] = false;
    $retour["message"] = "manque infos";
    }

echo json_encode($retour);
    // close the database connection
    $pdo = NULL;
?>
```

The result from POSTMAN is not really "speaking", but I can't to find other informations (in the log files) to help me...

Comment: If your schema has 'id' as auto-increment, this will fail.  Remove it from the list of fields and from the list of parameters. If not, you are missing a bind for 'id'

Comment: I do it, but it the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

[edit to be conform at the previous code]

I think my problem come from my "$_POST" because, when I tried to put some values into the "INSERT" line, that works well.

ex:

```
$requete = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO api (id,ville_depart, ville_destination, date_depart, nb_heure_vol, prix) VALUES ('123', 'LYON', 'TLS', '2019-09-09', '13', '132')");
$requete->execute();
```

Comment: No ID in this one, not the same statement, no parameters bound, possibly not even via a web server triggered execution (ie a different runtime context). This changes so many things that you cant isolate any single cause.

Comment: Sorry, because I try to find the solution. I edit my post to be conform.